# Has anyone installed the mlpack library for windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, mlpack

I have tried following various steps to install the mlpack library for windows 10, but was not successful. If any of you were able to please forward the link to the steps followed.

Answer (score 0):

Classic: https://www.mlpack.org/doc/mlpack-git/doxygen/build_windows.html

For Python: https://www.mlpack.org/doc/stable/doxygen/python_quickstart.html

Basically `pip install mlpack/mlpack3`

Comment: A bit more explanation of your answer would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Pip does not currently provide a working package for Windows (this is something that is actively being worked on), but there is a build guide for how to build on Windows that should work successfully:

http://mlpack.org/doc/stable/doxygen/build_windows.html

I used this recently (though on Windows 7) and had no issues.